# Ubuntu 16.04 locks up when screen turns off

Tags: 16.04, lockup

I have just set up a desktop box with Ubuntu 16.04.  It is working fine, except it locks up when the display shuts off per system settings under brightness & lock.  I researched this a little and found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485481/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-screen-is-locked-and-blank) that suggests editing /etc/default/grub to set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

and [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above) that says the parameter you have to change on recent Ubuntu releases is "autosuspend_delay_ms".  I have tried both using the procedure in the first link, and the autosuspend value remains 2 even after changing the grub conf file and restarting it. I can't find out what the 2 value that is set is supposed to indicate.

The second link suggests some other things to try but it's not clear that these apply to Ubuntu. I don't want to mess around until I know I'm doing the right thing because I don't want to hose my nice clean install.

Other things I've read says this applies to laptops that shut down USB to save power, but this is a desktop so maybe usbcore.autosuspend is not even what is causing the lock up.

Can anyone recommend a way to proceed?

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after adding the parameter to the grub configuration files?

Comment: Yes I did. No messages or errors when I ran it.

Comment: Turns out the solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-ubuntu-16-04/892783).