# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not responding after screen off

Tags: 16.04, suspend, freeze

After I lock my system and my screen goes off (black), it doesn't wake up anymore. As soon as that happens, I have to use my power button to reboot the system, else I will not be able to login.

I tried disabling USB auto suspend, as suggested over here: [Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't wake up after screen is locked and blank](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485481/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-screen-is-locked-and-blank) which did not work for me, unfortunately.

For now I have set the "Turn screen off when inactive for:" to "Never", via All Settings -> Brightness & Lock. Hopefully that will fix it for now, but if anyone knows a proper solution, please let me know :)

EDIT: Setting "Turn screen off when inactive for:" to "Never", does not work! After locking my system, the screen will turn black anyway and I'll unable to login again.

**EDIT:**

Alright, so xscreensaver seems to be the solution for now. But you have to make sure you set "Blank After" (through the settings of xscreensaver) to a couple of hours or something, because as soon as it goes "Blank", the same issue occurs. I've set it to 600 minutes for now, because I always shutdown my pc after work, but I have to make sure it keeps working while I'm at work so I don't have to force restart it after a meeting for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug report for that issue.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1617471

Comment: Thanks for the tip ;) It seems that the suggestion to install xscreensaver (`sudo apt install xscreensaver`), given on bugs.launchpad.net, solves the problem!